# "create a new blog entry" link using views in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, view

I am working on a blog in drupal and using the view module. I have created a view to show the latest entries but i would like to add just one link called, "create a new blog entry" on the blog view. Just like the actual drupal blog. Is this possible? If yes, how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing your view, click on `Header` under "Basic Settings" and add the following:

```
<?php
  print l('Create a new blog entry', 'node/add/blog');
?>
```

Make sure the input format of the `Header` section you are filling in is set to **PHP code** or else you will see that code printed out as text.  You can also add this to the `Footer` area of 'Basic Settings' if you want this link at the bottom of the view.

Comment: thank you, perfect solution but i was thinking of actually creating one in my node-blog.tpl.php

Comment: No problem, and you can use the same code (w/o Views instructions) to display a link in your node-blog.tpl.php file as well

Comment: In case you use your own content type for blogging, replace "blog" in the print statement with the machine name of the content type. For example if machine name of your content type is "my_blog_type", then the second argument would be 'node/add/my_blog_type'.